# jenkins shared library issue

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, groovy

i have a shared library with test branch, i have added shared lirary repo at folder level in jenkins and default version is develop, but i am trying to call test branch with same library ID.
for this i added below line in my jenkinsfile where i am calling functions,
@Library('aws_deploy_pipeline@test/branch-name') _

in logs i see shared library repo is checkout, but i am getting error that function is not known.

logs:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'test/branch-name' found among steps [list of]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.

Comment: Did you try to refer the guide here https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ ?

Comment: could you name the branch test_branch_name? I suspect "/" here may cause trouble (not tested. just speculation)